# Button with dashed outline - 9patch with tileMode="repeat"?

Tags: android, button, background, repeat, nine-patch

I am having trying to accomplish this kind of a design. It needs to stretch to accomodate difference screens but rather then stretching it should repeat the pattern, I think the picture is pretty self-explanatory. 9patch only wont cut it as it only stretches.

[image]

Thanks for your time

Comment: AFAIK your only option is to create pngs that fit the various screen sizes and include them in drawables-ldpi,mdpi,hdpi etc... folders

Comment: Can't you simply use a `shape` drawable with the stroke set on it?

Comment: ..doh.. make it an answer, please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest method to do what you want would be to use a `shape` drawable with the `stroke` element set on it to obtain that dash pattern.

You may be able to also do it with a `layer-list` drawable.